# bijection between prime ideals of $R_p$ and prime ideals of $R$ contained in $P$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Given a ring $R$, I want to show that the localization of $R$ at the prime ideal $P$ of $R$ (denoted as $R_P$) is isomorphic to the set of prime ideals of $R$ contained in $P$. That is:

$$
\text{Spectrum}(R_P)\cong \{I\subseteq P \mid \text{$I$ is an ideal of $R$}\}
$$

From the statment, I can see that $Q\subseteq R_P$ is a prime ideal, then any $x\in Q$ is of the form $x=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a\in R$, but $b\notin P$, from the definition of $R_P$. But how can I show that each such $Q$ relates to an ideal of $R$ contained in $P$.

Comment: It's hard to believe that a ring is isomorphic to a set of prime ideals. You must be talking about the spectrum of $R_P$ which is, btw, a set of *prime* ideals..

Comment: yes, so I have a set of prime ideals in $R_P$ mapping to a set of ideals in $R$ contained in $P$

Comment: Is there any textbook in commutative algebra not proving this?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've checked the recommended textbook for my module, but can't seem to find the proof. It is mentioned in my lecture notes, but the proof is left as an excercise

Comment: Is $R$ any ring or can we assume it is commutative?

Comment: Yes, R is assumed to be commutative

Comment: Can you please edit your question to address user26857's comment: your question confuses the localisation of a ring with a set of ideals of a ring.

Comment: Andrew Brick i think the true statement is this: $Spec(R_P)\cong \{I\in Spec(R)|I\subseteq P \}$; if so please edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sketch:**

Let $\,i\colon R\to R_\mathfrak p$, $\,x\mapsto \dfrac x1$ be the canonical morphism. If $\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec}R_{\mathfrak p}$, $\,\mathfrak p'=i^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ is a prime ideal of $R$  contained in $\mathfrak p$.

It is straightforward to check the inverse  of this mapping is $\,.\mathfrak p'\mapsto \mathfrak p'R_\mathfrak p$

Comment: The O.P. doesn't seem to have thought of this. I only made the relation explicit.

Comment: For the first direction in the bijection, I think you meant $\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec}R_{\mathfrak p}$. Right?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Proof for $Spec(R_P)\cong \{I\in Spec(R)|I\subseteq P \}$:
More generally, The book, "*Steps in Commutative Algebra*" by *Sharp* has:

[image]

Consider $S=R-P$.

Theorem 5.37 of the book  has similar result for even *primary* ideals.

Comment: 5.23 NOTATION.  let S be a multiplicatively closed
subset of the commutative ringR. let $f : R \to S^{-1}R$ denote the natural
ring homomorphism.  Use the extension and contraction notation for $f$ .