# Show that $\mathrm{Spec}\, R_{\mathfrak p}=\{\mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}\mid \mathfrak q\subset \mathfrak p, \mathfrak q\in\mathrm{Spec}(R)\}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ a commutative ring. I'm trying to show that $$\mathrm{Spec}( R_{\mathfrak p})=\{\mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}\mid \mathfrak q\subset \mathfrak p, \mathfrak q\in Spec(R)\}.$$
I recall that $$R_{\mathfrak p}=\left\{\frac{x}{s}\mid s\notin \mathfrak p\right\}.$$

For the inclusion $\supset$ I did as follow. Suppose by contradiction that it's not prime, i.e., there is $\frac{x}{s},\frac{x}{s'}\in \mathfrak qR_{\mathfrak p}$ s.t. neither $\frac{x}{s}$ nor $\frac{x'}{s'}$ are in $\mathfrak q R_{\mathfrak p}$.

I can't arrive to a contradiction. For the other inclusion, I have no idea.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: $R_{\mathfrak p}=\left\{\frac{x}{s}\mid s\notin \mathfrak p\right\}$ is not _quite_ right. Especially if the complement of $\mathfrak p$ contains zero divisor it's important to keep in mind that the elements in the localisation are _equivalence classes_ of the above set, signifying that you're allowed to simplify and expand any fraction.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $\frac{x}{s}\frac{x'}{s'}\in\mathfrak(q)R_{\mathfrak p}$. The comma is in error, and you are missing the $'$ character.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280885

Comment: @Arthur The implicit assumption is that  $\mathfrak p$ is prime, so $\mathfrak p$ doesn't have (relevant) zero-divisors, and the definition is good enough.

Comment: @ThomasAnsrews $\{(n,0)\mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, even though there are zero divisors everywhere, both inside and outside the ideal, and you're allowed to localise at that ideal.

Comment: How is the notation $\frac{x}{s}$ problematic in that case? @Arthur

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That depends. If you see $\frac xs$ as a true fraction that may be simplified and expanded to give the same value, then it's not problematic, but if you see it as an ordered pair, then it is problematic. I guess I was a bit quick on the trigger.

Comment: @Arthur $\frac{x}{s}$ is always an equivalence class of ordered pairs. The *real* risk is if you think of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as somehow a subset of some "larger" ring of fractions, like a field of fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm going to sketch the main steps of the proof. First let's set ourselves straight:

$$\mathfrak{q}R_{\mathfrak p}=\left\{\dfrac{x}{s}\bigg|
x\in \mathfrak{q},\ s\notin \mathfrak{p}\right\}$$

is the ideal generated in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ by the image of $\mathfrak q \subset R$ by $\phi: R\rightarrow R_{\mathfrak p},\ x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{1}$.
You actually need to prove that it is an ideal but it should be easy.

$\supseteq$: First let's prove it is prime. So you fix $\dfrac{x}{s},\ \dfrac{x'}{s'}\in R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ such that $\dfrac{xx'}{ss'}=\dfrac{y}{t}\in \mathfrak{q}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, where $y\in \mathfrak{q}$ and $t\notin\mathfrak{p}$. Thus by the définition of localisation you get $\sigma\notin\mathfrak{p}$ such that:
$$\sigma(yss' -txx')= 0$$
Thus you get $(\sigma t)xx'=\sigma yss'\in\mathfrak{q}$ but $\sigma t\notin \mathfrak{p}$ so $\notin\mathfrak{q}$ thus $xx'\in\mathfrak{q}$ thus $x\in \mathfrak{q}$ or $x'\in \mathfrak{q}$.

$\subseteq$: You take $\mathfrak Q$ prime in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ and consider
$$\mathfrak{q}=\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{Q})$$
By construction you know that it is prime.

In fact what we need to do, is prove that these constructions are reciprocal one to another.

Thus you need to prove $(1)$:
$$\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q} R_{\mathfrak p})=\mathfrak q$$

and $(2)$:
$$\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{Q})R_{\mathfrak p}=\mathfrak Q$$

You should be able to handle this easily, much like what I have done in $\supseteq$. Tell me if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a canonical homomorphism $\varphi:R\rightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ by sending $x\mapsto x/1$, prime ideals $\mathfrak{q}$ in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ go to prime ideals in $R$ under the preimage of $\varphi$. In symbols $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ is a prime ideal in $R$. If $\mathfrak{q}':=\varphi(\mathfrak{q})$ is not contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ then there are elements in $\mathfrak{q}'$ inside $R-\mathfrak{p}$ these elements are units in $\mathfrak{q}$ so this is a contradiction. We must have $\mathfrak{q'}\subset \mathfrak{p}$.